# CCAP sonar exception

Tags: java

I am facing issue while running ccap...sonar exception...no such method error.

Please find log content.

> Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java/util/Properties.load(Ljava/io/Reader;)V
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:288)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? - Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java/util/Properties.load(Ljava/io/Reader;)V
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at com.pmd.rules.custom.HibernateStmtRule.loadSqlInProperties(HibernateStmtRule.java:161)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at com.pmd.rules.custom.HibernateStmtRule.(HibernateStmtRule.java:152)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1243)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseSingleRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:309)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:253)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:209)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:157)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:146)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleReferenceNode(RuleSetFactory.java:365)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleNode(RuleSetFactory.java:255)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.parseRuleSetNode(RuleSetFactory.java:209)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:157)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory.createRuleSet(RuleSetFactory.java:146)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.readRuleSet(PmdExecutor.java:115)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.createRulesets(PmdExecutor.java:107)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executeRules(PmdExecutor.java:89)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executePmd(PmdExecutor.java:75)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.execute(PmdExecutor.java:61)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor.analyse(PmdSensor.java:52)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:64)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:91)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:129)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:68)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:147)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:136)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:68)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:83)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:68)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:106)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.executeBatch(Launcher.java:69)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.runner.internal.batch.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:61)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
>   13:44:02,035  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:285)
>   13:44:02,051  INFO ProgressExecutor:? -     ... 3 more
>   13:44:02,831  INFO DatabaseController:? - Database Shutdown initiated...
>   13:44:03,080  INFO ProgressExecutor:? - Job not completed and CANCEl_STATUS.
>   13:44:03,112  INFO ProgressExecutor:? - Exception occured during CCAPAction Analysis:CCAP Analysis error occured, please refer the ccap log for more details

Comment: Please provide the code that you're trying to run and format your post appropriately.

Comment: it's showing for all codes

Answer (score 0):

**You need to upgrade your Java to at least Java6.** The errormessage you got is informing you that the following method:

```
java/util/Properties.load(Ljava/io/Reader;)
```

is not available. It is because this function was added in [Java6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) and is not present in [Java5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Comment: M running CCAP in RAD eclipse...did u mean 6th version of RAD eclipse...?

Comment: Your *Java* version is really old. If you cannot understand this statement, you should not do complex stuff like this. I am not joking or complaining, I am serious.

Comment: but it was working in same java eclipse last month..it's RAD eclipse version 1